# Conditional probability with absolute continuous random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, absolute-continuity

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. Let $Y$ be a random variable taking the values 0 or 1. Let $X$ be some absolutely continuous random variable taking values in say $[0,1]$.

Let us consider the following probability:
$ \mathbb{P}(Y=1 |X=x)$.

1.) Is this even well defined? Since $X$ is an absolutely continuous RV, the probability for any $X=x$ is zero, so what does it mean to condition on an event of zero probability?

If we were to use Bayes theorem, we would have to deal with an expression involving $\mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=1) $.

2.) Again this shouldnt be defined since $X$ is an absolutely continuous RV. So am I not allowed to use Bayes theorem here?

Comment: Both conditional probabilties are well-defined in the sense that $\Bbb P_{X,Y} = \Bbb P_Y\otimes \Bbb P_{X|Y} = \Bbb P_X\otimes \Bbb P_{Y|X}$ where the lhs is the joint probability. Note that conditional probabilities are defined through integration, so their uniqueness is only a.e. In particular you can change them at every single point and they would still work in case your variables are continuous.

Comment: But can I even write something like $\mathbb{P}(X=x)$ for an absolutelz continuous random variable? Okay so I have two issues here: First a probability measure always takes a set and not a single number and the other issue is that for a continuous random variable every single element has probability zero, right?

Comment: Have you already covered conditional densities?

Comment: no not really but if it is required to bring your point across please still share it anyway. I will try to understand it

Comment: @SBF I have now learned about conditional densities. Can you give an answer now to my question?

Comment: Will try to tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's revisit the discrete case. The Bayes theorem in particular says that
$$
\Bbb P(Y \in B, X\in A) = \sum_{k\in A} \Bbb P(Y \in B|X = k)\Bbb P(X = k) = \int_A \Bbb P_{Y|X}(B|k)\Bbb P_X(\mathrm dk) \tag{1}
$$
where the last formula is just a rewriting of the first formula where we have just put as definition
$$
\Bbb P_{Y|X}(B| x) := \Bbb P(Y \in B|X = x)
$$
and $\Bbb P_X$ is the distribution of $X$: a probability measure induced by $X$ on its range. Note that $\Bbb P$ is a measure on $\Omega$ whereas $\Bbb P_X$ is a measure on $\Bbb N$ since in the discrete case $X:\Omega\to \Bbb N$. These two measures are related by $\Bbb P_X(x) := \Bbb P(X = x)$ or more generally $\Bbb P_X(A) = \Bbb P(X \in A)$ for any measurable $A \subset \Bbb N$.

If something up until now is not clear, try re-reading it, we don't do anything here, just renaming things and recalling the definitions that are sometimes not understood thoroughly when met the first time.

Now, the trick is that $(1)$ is not just the property of conditional distribution in the discrete case. It is their defining property, meaning that we can use that as a definition. Any function $\mu(B|k)$ that solves
$$
\Bbb P(Y\in B,X\in A) = \int_A\mu(B|k)\Bbb P_X(k) \tag{2}
$$
is a (version of) conditional distribution $\Bbb P_{Y|X}$. Note that this function is only uniquely defined for $k$ where $\Bbb P_X(k) > 0$. Indeed, if $\Bbb P_X(k) = 0$ for some $k$, then no matter how we change $\mu(B|k)$ it will not affect the validity of $(2)$. That's why we say that $(2)$ defines $\Bbb P_{Y|X}$ uniquely only $\Bbb P_X$-a.s.

If $Y$ is discrete as well, by taking $B = \{j\}$, single element sets, we can also define a conditional probability mass function $P_{Y|X}(j, k) := \Bbb P_{Y|X}(\{j\}, k)$. Obviosly immediately from definition it has the property that
$$
P_{Y|X}(j, k) = \Bbb P(Y = j|X = k).
$$

Finally, for the contiunous case we can take $(2)$ as the *definition* of the conditional probability. Namely, a function $\mu$ is a conditional probability of $Y$ given $X$ if and only if it satisfies
$$
\Bbb P(Y \in B,X \in A) = \int_A \mu(B|x)\Bbb P_X(\mathrm dx) 
$$
or equivalently if $P_X$ has density $p_X$ (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure):
$$
\Bbb P(Y \in B,X \in A) = \int_A \mu(B|x)p_X(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
Now, if it so happens that $\mu(B|x)$ also has density $m(y,x)$ (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure) for each $x$ then the last formula becomes
$$
\Bbb P(Y \in B,X \in A) = \int_B\int_A m(y,x)p_X(x)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \tag{3}
$$
and we call any $m$ that solves $(3)$ for each measurable $A$ and $B$ a (version of) conditional density of $Y$ given $X$.

Note that if we have some $m$ that solve $(3)$, we can change it at any single point, it will still solve $(3)$. We can even change it at a infinitely (but countably) many points and it will still solve $(3)$. We can even find an uncountable set which has $0$ measure w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^2$ and change $m$ there the way we like, and it will still solve $(3)$. For example, such set can be a circle, a straight line etc. That's why for no $x,y$ the value of $m(y,x)$ is fixed, only the overall shape of it matters since it is defined through the integral equation $(3)$. For this reason, for continuous random variables expressions $\Bbb P(Y = y|X = x)$ are undefined, meaning that this value can be anything and it will not affect anything. In contrast, values of the kind $\Bbb P(Y \in B|X \in A)$ for any $A$ such that $\Bbb P_X(A) > 0$ are strictly fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the long and clear answer. I have two questions left. 
1.) If, say, $Y$ is discrete but $X$ is continuous. Then $\mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=y) $is not defined, correct? But what about  $\mathbb{P}(Y=y|X=x)$, is this well defined? I.e., here we condition on a continuous random variable but fix one specific outcome $x$ for this random variable, which however has probability zero w.r.t. $\mathbb{P}_X$, right? So what does it mean to condition on an event of zero probability?
2.) What does this imply for Bayes theorem? Does it not exist for this case since $\mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=y)$ is not defined?

Comment: 1. Nope, if $Y$ is discrete then $\Bbb P(X = x|Y = y)$ must be $0$ if $\Bbb P(Y = y)> 0$ and can be anything oterhwise.

Comment: 2. Bayes theorem in continuous case reads as 
$$\int_A\Bbb P_{Y|X}(B|x)\Bbb P_X(\mathrm dx) = \int_B\Bbb P_{X|Y}(A|y)\Bbb P_Y(\mathrm dy)$$
for all measurable $A$ and $B$. That determines relation between $\Bbb P_{Y|X}$ and $\Bbb P_{X|Y}$ a.s.

Comment: thanks for your answers, so $mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=y)$ must be 0 if $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)>0$ because an atom always must have 0 probability?

And what about $\mathbb{P}(Y=y|X=x)$ for X continuous. How is that defined? I.e., what does it mean to condition on an event with measures 0?

Comment: First: yes, exactly and only for this reason. Second: that’s the point, it’s not uniquely defined. Think of it as the following: let’s say you need to find a function $p$ such that $\int_0^3 p(x) \mathrm dx = 1$. What is $p(2)$?

Comment: Thanks again. I guess it doesnt matter as it is a null set?
What does that mean then for $\mathbb{P}(Y=y|X=x)$ where $Y$ is discrete and $X$ is continuous? That it is arbitrary?

Comment: @guest1 do you know about the space $L^2$?

Comment: yes how does it relate?